# Constraints on mixed mode in xsd

Tags: xml, xsd

I want to make an xsd that will allow something like the following:

```
<document>
  Here is first paragraph with e.g. <i>itallic</i> and <b>bold</b>.

  <p>Here is the second paragraph also with some <i>itallic</i></p>

  <p>Here is the third paragraph</p>

  <!-- If there is any character data here it should be rejected -->
</document>
```

E.g., I want to allow the first paragraph to not have a <p> tag arround it, but subsequent paragraphs must have it.

Any hints on what I should look at? It seems to me that I cannot get what I want by putting mixed="true" on a complexType definition.

Update: It is not because the first paragraph is special. It is simply because I want to avoid having to write some tags. For example, I would like to be able make an order list by this:

```
<ol>
   <le>Here is the first list element, only one paragraph, easy to write</le>
   <le>Here is the second element.
       <p>The second element has an extra paragaph.</p>
   </le>
</ol>
```

The normal case will be that there is only one paragraph in each list element so it is annoying having to write both <le> and <p>. Still, I want to support the unusual case of multiple paragraphs in a list element.

Comment: Do you have an attempt that you have tried that you can share?

Comment: Sometimes when XSD doesn't allow a certain design, it's because the designers of XSD didn't want to encourage people to use XML in that way. Sometimes I think they were right.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, you cannot get what you want with XSD 1.0. While the XSD 1.0 mixed content may control the order and number of child elements appearing in an instance XML, it cannot control the text within it. Splitting the two "realms" may be your only option, assuming you're not allowing any text outside the <p> tags: the first would be a mixed content, for the first paragraph, the others would be an arbitrarily repeating sequence of p tags with mixed or any content.

I am illustrating a possible example, assuming the first paragraph is "special" because is an "intro"; so for this XML:

```
<document> 
  <intro>Here is first paragraph with e.g. <i>itallic</i> and <b>bold</b>.</intro>  
  <p>Here is the second paragraph also with some <i>itallic</i></p>  
  <p>Here is the third paragraph</p>  
</document>
```

You can define something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--XML Schema generated by QTAssistant/XML Schema Refactoring (XSR) Module (http://www.paschidev.com)-->
<xsd:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsd:element name="document">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="intro">
          <xsd:complexType mixed="true">
            <xsd:sequence>
              <xsd:element name="i" type="xsd:string" />
              <xsd:element name="b" type="xsd:string" />
            </xsd:sequence>
          </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="p">
          <xsd:complexType mixed="true">
            <xsd:sequence minOccurs="0">
              <xsd:element name="i" type="xsd:string" />
            </xsd:sequence>
          </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

Of course, you'll have to refine how the markup may be used, but you get the idea... Your transformations could take care of stripping the <intro> tags as needed.

If your request for hints means what other schema languages you might use, then...

- If you can deploy XSD 1.1 schemas, the new `xsd:assert` may help you here.
- If you can deploy other schema languages, then Relax NG is your ticket; try this for an [introduction](http://www.xmlhack.com/read.php_item=1880).

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply! I think I understand your suggestion as basically having a "document" node which has mixed content directly inside it and a "document2" node which has a sequence p tags. Anyway, I understand that what I try is not possible with XSD 1.0 which was really what I was after. Unfortunately my editor (Eclipse) only supports DTD and XSD 1.0 so I have to stick with them.

Comment: @user1772004, you could try another route if you like. I like to think that an XML tag is supposed to convey semantics. So I would try to first identify what is the meaning of that "first" block of text, what is it that makes it special. Once you find that, call it as such in your XML markup. It'll make for easier use of your schema, and reading of XML.